# Retornar a ruta post enviándole datos en request desde controlador Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, post

Necesito retornar en un metodo de mi controlador a una ruta post enviandole su request con los parametros que recibe la funcion, esto es lo que llevo en mi controlador:

```
public function miFunciondeControlador()
{        
        $parametro1 = "valor1";
        $parametro2 = "valor2";
        $parametro3 = "valor3";
        $request_enviar = new Request();
        $request_enviar->setMethod('POST');
        $request_enviar->request->add(['parametro1' => $parametro1,'parametro2' => $parametro2,'parametro3' => $parametro3 ]); 
        //Necesito algo parecido a esto para llamar a esta ruta que es post que recibe un request
        return redirect()->route('miruta', ['request' => $request_enviar ]);//No funciona 

}
```

En el archivo de rutas esta es la ruta que necesito llamar:

```
Route::post('/miruta','miController@metodoCualquiera')->name('miruta');
```

Asi recibe los parametros la funcion que estoy intentando llamar:

```
     public function metodoCualquiera(Request $request)
     {
          $parametro1 = $request->parametro1;
          $parametro2 = $request->parametro2;
          $parametro3 = $request->parametro3;
          dd($request); //Imprime Vacio
     }
```

Comment: ¿qué no funciona? ¿muestra algún mensaje de error?

Comment: No funciona, la función no recibe los datos como un request por lo tanto no puede tomar los parametros, y sencillamente es como que esta totalmente vacio el request, le agregue un en la funcion metodoCualquiera y imprime vacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé qué intentas hacer con una especie de redirección a un POST, pero me atrevo a decir que es una mala práctica, es como si intentaras comunicar a dos controladores, pero además agregas un ingrediente qué es el HTTP Request.

---

Por convenciones de diseño, si dos métodos de uno o más controladores necesitan utilizar el mismo "código", entonces dicho código debe estar en otra capa, puede ser un modelo, servicio, repositorio, interfaz, trait, etcétera.

Dicho esto, tendríamos tres protagonistas y vamos a utilizar DI:

El servicio que recibe la información de ambos métodos y/o controladores

```
namespace App\Services;

class MiServicio
{
    public function recibirDatos($param1, $param2, $param3)
    {
       // procesar información...
    }
}
```

El primer método que muestras

```
public function miFunciondeControlador(MiServicio $servicio)
{        
    $parametro1 = "valor1";
    $parametro2 = "valor2";
    $parametro3 = "valor3";

    $servicio->recibirDatos($parametro1, $parametro2, $parametro3);
}
```

El segundo método, el que recibe el POST

```
public function metodoCualquiera(Request $request, MiServicio $servicio)
{
    $parametro1 = $request->parametro1;
    $parametro2 = $request->parametro2;
    $parametro3 = $request->parametro3;

    $servicio->recibirDatos($parametro1, $parametro2, $parametro3);
}
```

No olvides agregar los `use App\Services\MiServicio;` respectivos.